# Chat page scroll should start from the end in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have implemented the chat in react js, When open conversation then on popup scroll is going down which is weared. scroll should saty by default from end same as facebook, slack etc..

Here is my implementation. Chat message are coming from server here I am giving as static.
Current working as like this. https://gyazo.com/cac3862795f22ec08dc4448c6ebd7e39
it should not scroll but directly start by end just like slack and facebook.

```
const messages = [
  {message: 'message1'},
  {message: 'message2'},
  {message: 'message3'},
  {message: 'message4'},
  {message: 'message5'},
  {message: 'message6'},
  {message: 'message7'},
  {message: 'message8'},
  {message: 'message9'},
  {message: 'message10'},
  {message: 'message11'},
  {message: 'message12'},
  {message: 'message13'},
  {message: 'message14'},
  {message: 'message15'},
  {message: 'message16'},
  {message: 'message17'},
  {message: 'message18'},
];


const scrollToEnd = () => {
    if (refForScrollingToLastElement.current) {
      refForScrollingToLastElement.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });

// Also tried this but same befaviour

/*const divHeight = refForScrollingToLastElement.current.offsetHeight;
      window.scrollBy(0, divHeight);

    }*/
  };


useEffect(() => {
scrollToEnd()
},[])


retun(
    <>
    <div>
messages.map(item => <p>{item.message}</p>)
</div>
<div
      ref={refForScrollingToLastElement}
      style={{
        height: 1,
        width: 100,
      }}
    ></div>
</>
```

I have tried that on conversation popup open scroll to bottom of page to see latest message there.

I am expecting scrool should start by default at the end but scoll behaviour should not show just like facebook, slack etc.

Comment: scrollIntoView will just make sure the element is visible on the page. probably want to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll

Answer (score 0):

You should use  `behavior: 'auto'` to avoid the scroll behavior. [Read More at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)